# C# Wrong text format when reading data from excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have an excel file with the test data like this:
Hà Thị minh Thắng
Hà Phúc Toàn

and i'm reading data from the excel file like this:

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog.FileName);
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets)
            {
                Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
                object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

                for (int i = 1; i <= values.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Person p = new Person();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= values.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                            if (null != values[i, j]) {
                                string s = values[i, j].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine("xxxx values[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + s);

                            }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

But, unfortunately this is what I got:
Hà Th? minh Th?ng
Hà Phúc Toàn

So,Could anyone please tell me the reason why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the console encoding first before outputting your strings to the console.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

A good place would be just after this code fragment in your code:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

Without `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`
[image]

With `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```csharp
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```

this is encoding for west EU letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string s = values[i, j].ToString();
```

Seems like the encoding of the text in excel spreadsheet differs. Try using a relevant Encoding.